# Two different radio button with one form and post it using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, radio-button

I am stuck with this code, trying to post 2 different radio group my problem is I want to make the user to check 1 radio button for ervery 4 results , I mean how can I know when user has choose other, with this code I always can choose more than one radio , any help?

```
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE object = '".$obj."' LIMIT 5 ";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

              echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
                  while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                    echo "<div align='center'>
                    <table class='demo'  dir='rtl'>
                      <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>".$row2['ojs']."</td>
                        <td> </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>".$row2['txt1']."</td>
                        <td><input type='radio' name='chk1' value='1' >
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>".$row2['txt2']."</td>
                        <td><input type='radio' name='chk2' value='2' >
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>".$row2['txt3']."</td>
                        <td><input type='radio' name='chk3' value='3' >
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>".$row2['txt4']."</td>
                        <td><input type='radio' name='chk4' value='4' >
                      </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table><br>
                    </div>
                    ";
                  }
                  echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>
                  </form>";
                  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $chk1 = $_POST['chk1'];
                    $chk2 = $_POST['chk2'];
                    $chk3 = $_POST['chk3'];
                    $chk4 = $_POST['chk4'];
                    echo $chk4."|".$chk3."|".$chk2."|".$chk1;

//insert into mysql , just the Selected radio button for each different question
$insQry = "insert into tbl2 (id,sel1,sel2,sel3,sel4) VALUES('$chk1','$chk2','$chk3','$chk4')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
                  }
```

Comment: why you guys votted down ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name of the entire adio input group to one name. Since you have them set to four different names, it treats them as as four different entities.

Comment: i did , and now the whole seprated radio in other tables acts like they are one group , i mean the whole page i can choose just one radio button even if there was more than 1 table

Answer (score 0):

You need to give them the same name then get it in PHP like

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE object = '".$obj."' LIMIT 5 ";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

          echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
              while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                echo "<div align='center'>
                <table class='demo'  dir='rtl'>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>".$row2['ojs']."</td>
                    <td> </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>".$row2['txt1']."</td>
                    <td><input type='radio' name='chk' value='1' >
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>".$row2['txt2']."</td>
                    <td><input type='radio' name='chk' value='2' >
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>".$row2['txt3']."</td>
                    <td><input type='radio' name='chk' value='3' >
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>".$row2['txt4']."</td>
                    <td><input type='radio' name='chk' value='4' >
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table><br>
                </div>
                ";
              }
              echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>
              </form>";
              if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $chk = $_POST['chk'];
                echo $chk;
```

Then simply set the adjacent one in the database to selected number and others to 0

Comment: i did , but what if there was more than 1 record fetch ? 
the same problem will remain

Comment: i have more than 1 fetch record , when i want to choose one radio for each table , i cant , it deals with all radio buttons as one group , not seprated

Comment: Give every group a separate name

Comment: So for example if the ojs field is unique in each row, then use name = '" . $row2['ojs'] '" as an example , if not use numbers , so define $number = 0; before the while loop  and use the name as this number,  then at the end use $number = $number + 1 ; or $number++;